# Mysql select Any one row FROM table_one WHERE columns having the same value occurs more than once, then output their data from table_two in an Array

Tags: php, mysql

Doesn't matter how many times a user_id appears in table_one, I just need select any of their user_ids e.g select any of (user_id = 8 and user_id = 12) then get their names and age from table_two then add them into an array.
Here are the tables:

table_one:

```
id   user_id   user_loves
1      8       Mango
2      5       Apple
3      1       Oranges
4      12      Toys
5      8       Guns
6      12      Bats
```

table_two:

```
id   user_id    name      Age
 1      8       David     19
 2      5       Michael   24
 3      12      Elsa     22
 4      4       Greg      26
```

Get any of user_id = 8 AND user_id = 12; then fetch the corresponding names and age from table_two and populate the result into an accessible array like so:

```
$result = array();
firstname = $result[0][name];
second_age - $result[1][age];
```

So that my final answer is

```
firstname = David
secondName = Elsa
second_age = 22
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a select distinct and left join

```
select distinct t1.user_id, t2.name,  t2.age 
from table_one t1
left join table_two t2 on t1.user_id = t2-user_id
```

Comment: Hello @scaisEdge Thanks for the answer, but I'm pretty new to MYSQL. Are t1.name, t2.age standard MYSQL keywords or can they also be written as table_one.user_id, table_one.name from table_one..?

Comment: t1. and t2 are alias of the table name  .. the alias i useful for don't repeat the same table name  when using a join there is more than one table.. you can use the alias you prefer ..

Comment: ok thanks @scaisEdge. But does your code select one instances of user_id = 8 and user_id = 12 on table_one?   I need to select only one instance of user_id 8 and user_id 12 then output their data from table_two.

Comment: if you can explain better  because  i don't undertsand  your comment .. you should try then  update  your question with the result and then post the real desired  result ..  (php and sql complaint)